# frida:hook a function but no response

Tags: javascript, java, android, hook, frida

I wrote a simple apk myself with a button that sends a request when pressed, this apk uses certificate verification, I tried to bypass it with hook, but it didn't work.

The following is part of the code for apk certificate verification.

```
X509TrustManager trustManager = new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                // Certificate returned by the server
                X509Certificate cf = chain[0];
                RSAPublicKey pubkey = (RSAPublicKey) cf.getPublicKey();
                String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(pubkey.getEncoded(), 0);
                Log.e("Certificate returned by the server：", encoded);

                // Reads the client's default certificate
                InputStream client_input = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.baidu);
                CertificateFactory finalcf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                X509Certificate realCertificate = (X509Certificate) finalcf.generateCertificate(client_input);
                String realPubKey = Base64.encodeToString(realCertificate.getPublicKey().getEncoded(), 0);
                Log.e("client's default certificate：", realPubKey);

                cf.checkValidity();

                final boolean expected = realPubKey.equalsIgnoreCase(encoded);

                Log.e("Call stack", Log.getStackTraceString(new Throwable()));

                if (!expected) {
                    throw new CertificateException("Certificate inconsistency");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
        };


        SSLSocketFactory factory = null;

        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{trustManager}, new SecureRandom());

            factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {

   }
```

I output the call stack below when i press the button.

```
at com.nb.netdemo3.MainActivity$2.checkServerTrusted(MainActivity.java:77)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:254)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptEngine.java:1644)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.ENGINE_SSL_read_direct(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.readDirectByteBuffer(NativeSsl.java:568)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(ConscryptEngine.java:1095)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1079)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:876)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:747)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:712)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:849)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.access$100(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:722)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:238)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:217)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:336)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:300)
```

And i want to hook this function `com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted`,here is the
hook code

```
Java.perform(function () {
    var Platform = Java.use('com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform');
    Platform.checkServerTrusted.overload('javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager', '[Ljava.security.cert.X509Certificate;', 'java.lang.String', 'com.android.org.conscrypt.AbstractConscryptSocket').implementation = function (x509tm, chain, authType, socket) {
        console.log('\n[+] checkServer  ', x509tm, JSON.stringify(x509tm));
        //return this.checkServerTrusted(x509tm, chain, authType, socket);
    };
});
```

I used frida to hook, and when I hooked, when I pressed the button to send the request, there was no `console.log`.
The version of frida is 16.0.1,my android version is 11,python version is 3.7.9.

I want to know why I can't hook this function called `com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted`

Comment: The github link I refer to is [link](https://github.com/google/conscrypt/blob/86ff4e3fd4b6b3bb76a7ec0e91290384401ccbf3/android/src/main/java/org/conscrypt/Platform.java),It's on line 429.And I didn't report any errors when I hooked this function.

Comment: Your mind is that there are two functions with the same name, but with different parameters, and I hook the one that doesn't execute, so what are these two functions and their parametersCan you say that again? I'll try later . Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hooking code is correct, but it just hooks the wrong overloaded version of `checkServerTrusted`, therefore you don't get an error but your code inside the hook is never executed:

The class `com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform` contains two public implementations of `checkServerTrusted`:

- [`checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManager, X509Certificate[], String, AbstractConscryptSocket)`](https://github.com/google/conscrypt/blob/bc1a34b5e199df1d09fe5735d287f18c5e79bdd7/android/src/main/java/org/conscrypt/Platform.java#L431)
- [`checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManager, X509Certificate[], String, ConscryptEngine)`](https://github.com/google/conscrypt/blob/bc1a34b5e199df1d09fe5735d287f18c5e79bdd7/android/src/main/java/org/conscrypt/Platform.java#L451)

You have hooked the first version, but looking at the code in [com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine](https://github.com/google/conscrypt/blob/bc1a34b5e199df1d09fe5735d287f18c5e79bdd7/common/src/main/java/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngine.java#L1635C86-L1635C86) where checkServerTrusted is called (see your stack trace) you will see that the last argument is a `this` thus the second version is called where the last argument type is `com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine`.

So f you your hooking code to the following script it should work.

```
Java.perform(function () {
    var Platform = Java.use('com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform');
    Platform.checkServerTrusted.overload('javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager', '[Ljava.security.cert.X509Certificate;', 'java.lang.String', 'com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine').implementation = function (x509tm, chain, authType, engine) {
        console.log('\n[+] checkServer  ', x509tm, JSON.stringify(x509tm));
        //return this.checkServerTrusted(x509tm, chain, authType, socket);
    };
});
```

Note that the linked source code references do not belong to the Android version of your device, therefore the line numbers don't match and it would be possible that in your older version the code is different.

If you want to get the exact code that is executed on your device you would have to extract the Android Framework libraries from your device and decompile them (not sure which files you would have to extract from `/system/framework` to get the conscrypt byte code).

Comment: The technique proved to be effective. Your assistance was greatly appreciated. Your expertise was truly remarkable.

Comment: So to summarize, if hook doesn't respond later, it's probably either not executing the function, or the function is overloaded, right?

Comment: I have another hook problem. I try to hook the write and read functions underlying https, but it still doesn't respond.like this, `Java.perform(function () {     var ByteString = Java.use("com.android.okhttp.okio.ByteString");     var OutputStream = Java.use('com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLOutputStream');      OutputStream.write.overload('[B', 'int', 'int').implementation = function (v1,v2,v3) {         console.log(ByteString.of(v1).utf8(), "\n");         return this.write(v1,v2,v3);     }; });`

Comment: My android version is 11,i guess it may not execute the write function  in `com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLOutputStream`